# Why is Dane Mechnikov alive in "Annals of the Heechee"?

Tags: heechee-saga

In Frederik  Pohl's fourth novel of the Heechee saga, Robin Broadhead encounters Gelle-Klara Moynlin together with Dane Mechnikov. It is mentioned that he was on the same expedition as Klara when they got stuck in the black hole. I remember from an earlier book that Wan and his companion rescued Klara but they told her that she was the sole survivor. So how come that Dane is still around, especially in meat form?

Note: I haven't finished the book yet. But I doubt there will be an explanation of this conundrum.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out it is actually revealed later in the book. However it is not really satisfactory. During the meeting with Klara and Dane, Robin's doppel gets told that Klara went back to the black hole to rescue Dane and the others. This would imply that Wan only rescued Klara and left the others behind. Which raises even more questions. Wan seemingly lied (which is believable) about Klara being the only survivor, but also he managed to only take her from the Heechee ship and no one else. This is hardly believable, since the ship was pretty small. There surely must have been a struggle because everyone would have wanted to escape.
So I think this is a bit of badly designed part of the plot. Not sure what Dane's role is at this point. I haven't finished the book either yet, so I will have to wait and see.

Comment: When you return, don't forget to self-accept the answer (and possibly [edit] in more details from having finished the book).

Answer (score 0):

As I listen to this on an audiobook I had the same question and came to the same conclusion that Wan had lied. This is speculation but maybe he saw “woman” and grabbed her. As I understand it they were unconscious, right?

Edit: I also think some of the plot is haphazard and reviews I’ve read seem to think much of this book has a poor plot. So far I enjoy it, but certainly see the flaws.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't add an answer just to agree with another answer; you should post a comment instead.  Do you have a reference for them being unconscious?